# Movie where a memory is switched between people which helps to solve a murder

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie in which a female police officer takes the memory of a dying victim to catch her murderer.

I remember a scene from the movie where the officer's husband, who is a scientist, shows her his experiment that involves exchanging memories between mice.

Comment: Any idea of what year/region it was released? What the characters looked like? The setting?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Strange Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_(film))?

> Strange Days is a 1995 American science fiction thriller film directed
>   by Kathryn Bigelow, written by James Cameron and Jay Cocks, and
>   produced by Cameron and Steven-Charles Jaffe. It stars Ralph Fiennes,
>   Angela Bassett, Juliette Lewis, and Tom Sizemore. Set in the last two
>   days of 1999, the film follows the story of a black marketeer of SQUID
>   discs, recordings that allow a user to experience the recorder's
>   memories and physical sensations, as he attempts to uncover the truth
>   behind the murder of a prostitute.

Comment: Sorry not that movie

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Unforgettable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unforgettable_(1996_film))?

> *The film is about a man named David Krane (Liotta), who is obsessed
> with finding out who murdered his wife.*
>
> *Later, Dr. Krane goes to a dinner where Dr. Martha Briggs gives a lecture on her experiment to transfer memories via cerebral spinal fluid. After the lecture Dr Krane makes an appointment with Dr. Briggs to go over her research. Dr, Briggs is then approached by an unidentified woman who tells her that Dr. Krane was a suspect in his wife's murder, and if the police department had not botched the investigation he would be on death row.*
>
> *The following day, at Dr. Briggs office, she goes over the
> experimental procedure. She states that neuro-peptides are used in
> forming memories and can be retrieved from Cerebral Spinal Fluid
> (CSF). However, the peptides themselves are not enough to transfer
> memories; Therefore, she has created a serum designed to facilitate
> the memory transfer process. however, the serum is not enough and an
> external stimulus similar to the memory must also be present for the
> memories to successfully imprint on the recipient. She gives Dr. Krane
> a demonstration and they discuss the formula and side effects of the
> procedure. Dr. Krane suggests using nitroglycerin to alleviate the
> side effects, but Dr. Brigs mentions that that would only be a short
> term fix, and the long term complications would still exist. Dr, Krane
> inquires as to when human trials might start, and she explains she a
> long way away from that, at least 7 years. Dr. Krane says he would be
> willing to volunteer to try the serum, and Dr. Briggs responds that
> not only would it be dangerous, it would be unethical. Dr. Krane
> apologizes and then leaves.*

Comment: Not really.I only remember the first scene where a mouse was able to find way from a maze just because he has memory of some other mouse.

Comment: @AnuragChand - I've not seen it, but the trailer (0:48) shows a rat running through a maze.